# IF statement between ints and atoms

Tags: erlang

I been messing around with this piece of code for a couple hours and I still don't know what I'm doing wrong i have other functions and this is the only one i been having trouble with.

```
-module(if_statements).

-export([weather/1]).

weather(TEMP) ->

if 

    TEMP <= 0 ->

        io:fwrite("freezing\\n");

    0 < TEMP <= 10 ->

        io:fwrite("cold\\n");

    10 < TEMP <= 20 ->

        io:fwrite("normal\\n");

    20 < TEMP <= 30 -> 

        io:fwrite("hot\\n");

    30 < TEMP <= 40 -> 

        io:fwrite("heated\\n");

    40 < TEMP ->

        io:fwrite("hirviendo\\n").

    true -> 

        io:fwrite("unknown")

end.
```

**Shell**:
The shell hasn't been really helpful either

```
if_statements.erl:6:8: syntax error before: '<='

% 6| TEMP <= 0 ->

% | ^



if_statements.erl:18:8: syntax error before: '->'

% 18| true ->

% | ^



if_statements.erl:2:2: function clima/1 undefined

% 2| -export([weather/1]).

% |
```

Comment: 1. In erlang, "less than or equal to" is spelled `=<`.  The symbol `<=` is used for something else called a *binary comprehension*.  2. In erlang, you terminate an expression with a period, but you have a period in the middle of your if expression.  In erlang, you can't just add code to the end of a valid expression --the punctuation will necessarily need to change.

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen a piece of erlang production code that uses `if` statements. The preferred/best practice way to do this is via pattern matching and function heads. There are a few answers down below that demonstrate a good solution using pattern matching.

Answer (score 3):

@alias answer is the right one, although I'm pretty sure that the final `true` clause will never match since regardless of the value of `TEMP`, it will always fall into one of the previous clauses.
OTOH, you might want to consider [avoiding `if` statements altogether](https://github.com/inaka/erlang_guidelines#avoid-if-expressions) and just using a multi-claused function with guards…

```
weather(TEMP) when            TEMP =< 0  -> io:fwrite("freezing\n");
weather(TEMP) when  0 < TEMP, TEMP =< 10 -> io:fwrite("cold\n");
weather(TEMP) when 10 < TEMP, TEMP =< 20 -> io:fwrite("normal\n");
weather(TEMP) when 20 < TEMP, TEMP =< 30 -> io:fwrite("hot\n");
weather(TEMP) when 30 < TEMP, TEMP =< 40 -> io:fwrite("heated\n");
weather(TEMP) when 40 < TEMP             -> io:fwrite("boiling ;)\n");
weather(TEMP) -> io:format("unknown temperature: ~p", [TEMP]).
```

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is a bit off. Try the following:

```erlang
-module(if_statements).
-export([weather/1]).

weather(TEMP) ->
  if
      TEMP =< 0            -> io:fwrite("freezing\n");
      0 < TEMP, TEMP =< 10 -> io:fwrite("cold\n");
     10 < TEMP, TEMP =< 20 -> io:fwrite("normal\n");
     20 < TEMP, TEMP =< 30 -> io:fwrite("hot\n");
     30 < TEMP, TEMP =< 40 -> io:fwrite("heated\n");
     40 < TEMP             -> io:fwrite("hirviendo\n");
     true                  -> io:fwrite("unknown")
end.
```

Answer (score 1):

The function clauses (or if conditions) can simply look like this:

```
weather2(TEMP) when TEMP =< 0  -> "freezing";
weather2(TEMP) when TEMP =< 10 -> "cold";
weather2(TEMP) when TEMP =< 20 -> "normal";
weather2(TEMP) when TEMP =< 30 -> "hot";
weather2(TEMP) when TEMP =< 40 -> "heated";
weather2(_) -> "unknown".  %% this clause only matches if TEMP is greater than 40

test() ->
    print_weather(-10),
    print_weather(7),
    print_weather(20),
    print_weather(21),
    print_weather(35),
    print_weather(45),
    test_finished.


print_weather(TEMP) ->
    io:format("~3w => ~s~n", [TEMP, weather2(TEMP)] ).
```

Similar to an if expression, erlang examines the first function clause and if there's a match, that function clause is executed, and no subsequent functions clauses are examined after that.  If the clause doesn't match, then the next function clause is examined, etc.

output:

```
~/erlang_programs$ erl
Erlang/OTP 24 [erts-12.0.2] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:1]
Eshell V12.0.2  (abort with ^G)

1> c(a).
a.erl:2:2: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported
%    2| -compile(export_all).
%     |  ^

{ok,a}

2> a:test().
-10 => freezing
  7 => cold
 20 => normal
 21 => hot
 35 => heated
 45 => unknown
test_finished

3>
```

Also, very different in erlang(although not relevant here) is that the parameters of a function clause can be constants:

```
f1(X, 10) -> ... ;  %integer
f1(X, a)  -> ....;  %atom
f1(X, "hello") -> ...; %string (which is a shortcut for creating a list)
f1(3, [Name, Age, Phone]) -> something.
```

In most languages, all the parameters in a function definition have to be variables.

In erlang, *function clause matching* is an extremely powerful way to dissect parameters as well as control the flow of execution.